# Problems when switching to xcode 3.2.3 and simulator 4.0

Tags: iphone, xcode, gps, cllocationmanager

Here is a list of problems I have after building my app with xcode 3.2.3 and running it on simulator 4.0.
Of course, all these issues did work with the previous environment.

1. Location manager does not update location. It used to update with the location at Cupertino but now I get locationManager:didFailWithError: called with error 0.
2. I have a map view and the panning doesn't work. Moving the map around nor the pinching gesture.
3. When I click and hold on the map my app, sometimes, crashes and the Log says something about long touch.

Thanks,
Tzur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simulator no longer returns a faked location but tries to use your Mac's Airport to locate you. Do you have Airport activated?

Comment: It didn't work with the Airport activated either. I'm sure the WiFi location is not mapped.
Thanks for the information.